# qgis2web changes map projection

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis2web, climate

I have created a series of global maps containing climate change data through geologic time. I would like to display the data in interactive maps that contain drop downs with background information contained in the attribute tables. Web maps seem like a good medium for this, but the qgis2web plugin appears to be reprojecting the maps and distorting them.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea to complete these goals while maintaining the appearance of my original maps?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distorted screenshot is just a preview.
Export the map with the Export button.
In the Appearance tab you can click **Match Project CRS**.
So the exported project will keep your EPSG 4327, otherwise the default one will be taken which seems to me to be 3857.
Let me know if you can fix it.

Comment: That fixed it. Much easier than I expected!